# Terminate Window on another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a simple C# winform app where I spawn a new thread to show another winform. After a process is completed i want to close that form using the below code. The issue I have is that when I call `busyForm.BeginInvoke` it is bypassing the null check and throw and error. How to correctly close the winform in another thread?

```
static Indicator busyForm; 

public static async Task Execute()
        {
            Thread busyIndicatorthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(()=>FormThread()));
            busyIndicatorthread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            busyIndicatorthread.Start();
        }
        
           private static void FormThread()
        {
            busyForm = new Indicator();
            busyForm.Closed += (sender2, e2) => busyForm.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
            Dispatcher.Run();
        }

public static Task Execute(){
  
    Thread busyIndicatorthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(()=>FormThread(hwind)));
            busyIndicatorthread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            busyIndicatorthread.Start();
            
    // dos some stuff
            
     if (busyForm != null)
        {
            busyForm.BeginInvoke(new System.Action(() => busyForm.Close())); <--- throw null error
            busyForm = null;
        }
}
```

Comment: Having more than one UI threads is highly unusual. Are you sure that you want to go that route?

Comment: `where I spawn a new thread to show another winform.` why? No application does that, or even needs that. In all applications, the busy and progress dialog boxes are generated by the UI thread. Operations that could block are performed in the background, eg in a background thread or using `Task.Run`. The UI is updated using events or callbacks, eg using the `Progress< T>` class

Answer (score 2):

That is because before calling `.Close()` method, time has passed and it is not assured that busyForm exists anymore.
In fact, it is possible that, while the `new System.Action(() => busyForm.Close()` thread is starting, you main thread goes to `busyForm = null;`.

You can try moving the null to secondary thread.

```
    if (busyForm != null)
    {
       busyForm.BeginInvoke(new System.Action(() =>
       { 
          lock(busyForm){
            busyForm.Close();
            busyForm = null;
          }
       }));         
    }
```

Comment: You should never use a lock on something that can become null. lock on a null object will throw `ArgumentNullException` - not really an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Almost no application starts another message pump to display notifications. It's not needed. In all applications, the busy and progress dialog boxes are generated and displayed.by the UI thread. Operations that could block are performed in the background, eg in a background thread or far better, using `async/await` and Task.Run. The UI is updated using events or callbacks, eg using the [Progress< T>](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) class.

In this case though, it seems all that's needed is to display a form before a long-running task and hide it afterward:

```cs
public async void btnDoStuff_Async(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    //Disable controls, display indicator, etc
    btnDoStuff.Enabled=false;
    using var busyForm = new Indicator();
    busyForm.Show();

    try
    {
        var result=await Task.Run(()=> ActuallyDoStuffAndReturnResult());

        //Back in the UI form
        //Do something with the result
    }
    finally
    {
        //Close the busy indicator, re-enable buttons etc.
        busyForm.Close();
        btnDoStuff.Enabled=true;
    }
}
```

The `finally` block ensures the UI is enabled and the busy form hidden even in case of error.

20+ years ago some Visual Basic 6 applications *did* start another Window message pump to act as a "server". Visual Basic 6 threading was *very* quirky, so people used various tricks to get around its limitations.

Answer (score 1):

When you write this code:

```
        busyForm.BeginInvoke(new System.Action(() => busyForm.Close())); <--- throw null error
        busyForm = null;
```

The order in which it executes is almost certainly this:

```
        busyForm = null;
        busyForm.Close();
```

No wonder you're getting a null reference exception!

Simply set the form to null in your invoke. That'll fix it.

However, the correct way to do this is as Panagiotis Kanavos suggests.